# Gravatar image in Flickr?

Tags: flickr, gravatar

Can I link my Gravatar image to my Buddy Icon on Flickr using the web URL setting in my profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your current Gravatar image by selecting the web URL, but this will then be uploaded to Flickr's server, and will therefore not stay up to date with your Gravatar image. Basically this is no different to if you were to upload the image from your computer.

Therefore you cannot use Gravatar as your buddy icon.

Comment: It's a shame that Flickr doesn't just support Gravatar.